# Converting unknown date to human format in SQLite Database

Tags: ios, sqlite

There's an iOS app that I'm looking at where the SQLite table for date shows up as the following

ZRECORDDATE
423942471
423873218
423512431
423950419
423954082
423954975
424551647

at first I believe it was UNIX time but after using a converter - 1983 definitely isn't it.

I'm probably missing the obvious here but can anyone point me in the right direction for converting this to a human date/time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If they can't be 1983 dates, what can they be?

Comment: as far as I'm aware the dates they were recorded were in 2014/2015.  That is what's throwing me

Comment: Datetimes then, not dates?

Answer (score 0):

With your indication, it may be a time interval since 01 Jan 2001 in seconds.

```
let sec : TimeInterval = 423942471
let date=Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:Sec)
print("date \(date)")
```